# How to easily (as possible) can i get the source code for android java classes?

Tags: android, open-source

I'm trying to do something in my app, and in order to do that i need to see the source code for a few classes (it doesn't have to be through the workspace/eclipse, it can be on the internet, on another program, anywhere at all).

The thing is that even after seeing many many answers and explanations both here and in other sites, I still can't get it.

For example, some answers referenced to [here](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/).  but all the sources there are really old (2.1 is the newest...)

Or other answers referenced to [here](https://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/). but i couldn't understand what i need to do in order to install it. I think that there should be "Android Sources" available to download through the Android SDK manager, but I don't have such an option in my SDK Manager (I only have "Android support library/repository").

And then there's [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) that requires me to install a VM(!) first (I'm using Windows), and it's also quite complicated...

So can anyone tell me if there's a simple way to get the source code for android java classes? It doesn't have to be all of them at once, and it doesn't matter through what program, as long as it works on Windows. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So can anyone tell me if there's a simple way to get the source code for android java classes?

Use [a Web browser](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/).

If you use Chrome, you can also install [the "Android SDK Search" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin), which will add "(view source)" links towards the top of each class' JavaDocs.

Comment: +1 for the Chrome extension, this will be very useful indeed, thanks for sharing !

Comment: Thanks a lot! This Chrome extension is just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

> I think that there should be "Android Sources" available to download
>   through the Android SDK manager, but I don't have such an option in my
>   SDK Manager (I only have "Android support library/repository").

There is. Make sure you have the latest version of the Android SDK. The Sources are called "Sources for Android SDK". Also note that not all API-Levels have the sources available in the Android SDK Manager.